# Two qGraphicsScenes Vs. one qGraphicsScene + duplicate items

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsScene and a QGraphiscView. I have many items in the scene, with the behavior defined for each item sets. I call this normal mode. So in normal mode I can interact and see the items in the scene from the view. 
I want to create a X-ray mode, which basically means the position of all items in the scene is the same, but items and behaviors are different.
The question is which of the following is the better approach (or there is even better one) to switch between modes:

- Create a new scene, add items to the new scene on the same position as the old scene. To switch to x-ray mode, put view(scene) to the new scene.
- Keep only one scene, add items to the normal scene, but for switching to X-ray mode, only hide/show items.

From ease of implementation, efficiency and speed, which option is better? Is there any built-in options in Qt to do this?

Comment: You could also tell the items that x-ray mode has been activated, and handle that in the `QGraphicsItem::paint` function and what not. That way you don't need duplicate items or scenes. I don't know if this is a viable option for you though.

Comment: Paint is easy to implement. I can select items by usertypes to paint or hide. Thanks!